# Securily deploying applications to Windows Server

Tags: security, deployment, windows-server

How does one deploy an ASP.NET (MVC) application to a Windows Server securely? Visual Studio 2008 seems to only support FTP, which is not secure at all (plain text passwords) and http which I'm not really sure what it is. I've been told it is for FrontPage extensions and that I should use that, but that seems to really be a second class citizen in the Microsoft stack, and using only http (no s), I doubt it's security.

So, How does one deploy an ASP.NET (MVC) application to a Windows Server securely?

Answer (score 1):

FrontPage Server Extension is no longer recommended, and if you notice it is no longer maintained by Microsoft for IIS 7 (old versions are still supported by Microsoft).

Consider FTPS or WEBDAV over HTTPS/SSL which are feature rich and secure.

Comment: Can Visual Studio do https or ftps?

Answer (score 0):

http actually means [webdav](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), and I suggest you to always disable it unless you know what you are doing.

There may be tools to use ftps or the like; what I actually do is to "publish" locally on my pc and then manually copy to the server...

Comment: If you set up WEBDAV via HTTPS on the server side, you can simply map that site to a network drive. Then why not manually copy from your local drive to it?

Or if you have FTPS setup, use a client software can help copy your local files to that server.